# Totaling the values of multiple range sliders with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple range sliders in a Gravity Form. I want to calculate the totals of the user's choices and display on screen. The jQuery works and does what it should.

However I need the initial values of each slider to be zero and then stop them going over a total of 100, but if I use jQuery to set the initial value of each slider to zero with `$('.slider').val(0)` as suggested elsewhere, the value of #total remains always zero. How can I set initial values to zero and still get #total to display the sum of all slider values?

```js
$('.slider').on('change', function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.slider').each(function() {
    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
  });
  $('#total').text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="total"></p>
<input name="input_1" id="input_1_1" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" />
<input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" />
<input name="input_3" id="input_1_3" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" />
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where are you setting the values to zero? Why would they still be zero inside a change function? Why are you setting the value to 50 in the markup if you want them to be zero?

Comment: Because in gravity forms you cannot set the initial value, and it therefore uses the midpoint, ie 50, as the initial value.

Comment: I assume that's done prior to the change function running. If you want help you'll have to demonstrate the problem. It all seems to work now.

Comment: *"I want the initial slider values to be 0"* - than why you use `value="50"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the initial value of the number field to 0 using the Default Value under the Advanced Tab of the field in Gravity Forms

```
  $('.slider').val(0);
  $('.slider').on('change', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.slider').each(function() {
      sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    if (sum > 100) {//this will prevent the total from exceeding 100
      $(this).val($(this).val() - (sum - 100));
      sum = 100;
    }
    $('#total').text(sum);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, that's close to what I'm after now

Comment: Don't query the DOM on a "change" event for class elements over and over. Instead cache your `$('.slider')` in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the sliders are related, but

- Use a `type="range"` if you need *"sliders"*
- Cache your elements. It's not performant to go query the DOM on every input change onr input event.
- Use `.reduce()` to reduce a list (array or collection) to a different type (Number) in your case
- Use `Math.min()` to cap your value to a max of `100`

```js
const $slider = $(".slider");
const $total = $("#total");

$slider.on("input", () => {
  let sum = $slider.get().reduce((acc, el) => acc += parseInt(el.value ?? 0), 0);
  sum = Math.min(sum, 100);
  $total.text(sum);
});
```

```html
<input name="input_1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" />
<input name="input_2" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" />
<input name="input_3" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" />
<p id="total"></p>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Even with this solution (since you did not explained what are you actually after) it's a bad UX to let the user slide something uselessly - seeing a value result unchanged at *100*. I'll leave it up to you to figure out the actual UI requirements.